# How to mathematically prove that PCA can reduce noise?

Tags: pca

We know $X^TX=U\Sigma U$ and reconstructed data $Y=X\tilde{U}$ for k eigenvector corresponding with k largest eigenvalue. Then how to mathematically show that PCA can reduce noise?

I am thinking about using covariance of Y to prove that. That is, the covariance of reconstructed data is less than the original data. Then, the reconstructed data contains less information so the noise is reduced. But I cannot relate less covariance in data and less noise in data using mathematical language. Can anyone help?

Comment: What do you define as noise??

Comment: @Fiodor1234 The noise should be the rest terms with really small eigenvalues in covariance matrix.

Comment: In general, the PCA finds a lower-dimensional representation (by keeping the eigenvector of the first k principal components), by finding linear combinations of the columns of $X$, that are uncorrelated and maximally preserve the variance of the data. So, there is a connection between information that you lose (because you keep $k$ linear components) and the variance that your linear combinations explain. So, I don't think the noise term is the appropriate here.

Comment: @Fiodor1234 Appreciate the explanation. I totally get that PCA compresses data into low level and force the compressed data having only independent columns. Then is there anyway to measure the information loss during this process. Is the change in covariance matrix a good measurement?

Comment: Yes, exactly the covariance matrix can help you with that. A way to measure that is to examine how much variance you leave unexplained with the use of your new lower-dimensional linear combinations. Because the variance of the data $X$ is equal to the sum of all the eigenvalues. You can use something similar as in this picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQif4.png, where on y-axis they use the cumulative sum of eigenvalues in an increasing order.

Comment: @Fiodor1234 Got it. Highly appreciate that!

Comment: Re "the reconstructed data contains less information so the noise is reduced:" this is illogical.  To see why, suppose the first principal component contains all the noise, which predominates, and that the PCA retains just the first PC. (It is straightforward to construct data with this property and not difficult to imagine situations where it is a realistic model.) The result is to remove *all* the signal and retain *only* the noise!  Even though there is "less covariance," you can't conclude anything about the amount of "information."

Comment: @whuber indeed if we reduce dimension to the terms with high noise, we can't say PCA reduce noise. But isn't compressing data equivalence to losing insignificant information?

Answer (score 1):

First, as @Fiodor1234 mentioned, "less information" does not imply "less noise", and certainly not a lower ratio of noise to signal. Additionally, I don't think it is even clear what you mean by noise. Therefore, I intended to mention that there is no reason to believe PCA will reduce noise. However, I realized that that is not always true.

Consider a case where we draw observations with multiple features and

1. The features have some degree of correlation
2. The features are recorded with random measurement errors that are IID.

In this case, because PCA exploits correlation structure in the data, reconstructing the dataset using some subset of PCs will indeed yield a dataset that is less influenced by measurement error than the original. Consider this simulated example where data is drawn from a multivariate gaussian distribution and recorded with random normal errors. The measurements are reproduced by the PCs much more faithfully (higher $R^2$) than the measurement errors.

[image]

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import multivariate_normal
from sklearn.datasets import make_spd_matrix
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(777)

results ={
    'nComp': [],
    'Measure': [],
    'R2': []
}
N_obs = 1000
N_features = 20
for i in range(15):
    cov = make_spd_matrix(N_features)
    mean = np.array([0]*N_features)
    X = multivariate_normal(mean, cov, [N_obs])
    noise = np.random.normal(0,0.6, [N_obs, N_features])
    for nComp in range(1, N_features+1):
        pca = PCA()
        pca.fit(X+noise)
        X_hat = np.dot(pca.transform(X)[:,:nComp], pca.components_[:nComp,:])
        noise_hat = np.dot(pca.transform(noise)[:,:nComp], pca.components_[:nComp,:])
        X_noise_hat = np.dot(pca.transform(X+noise)[:,:nComp], pca.components_[:nComp,:])
        r2_X = r2_score(X,X_hat)
        r2_noise = r2_score(noise,noise_hat)
        r2_X_noise = r2_score(X+noise, X_noise_hat)
        results['nComp'] += [nComp]*3
        results['R2'] += [r2_X, r2_noise, r2_X_noise]
        results['Measure'] += ['True X', 'Measurement Error', 'Observed X']
        
results_df = pd.DataFrame(results)
plt.figure(figsize=(9,6))
sns.pointplot(data=results_df,x='nComp',y='R2', hue='Measure')
plt.ylim(0)
plt.ylabel("$R^2$ Score - Reconstruction vs Original")
plt.xlabel("Number of PCs")
plt.title("Proportion of Variance Explained \nvs Number of Principal Components")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. We should indeed define properties of noise before "reducing" it.